# NSURLSession with a offline URL

Tags: ios, url, swift, ios8, nsurlsession

I'm calling this line of code:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    ... 
}

task.resume()
```

but I would like to handle when the URL is offline, when I'm not receiving back information from the server.

I have no Idea of how to do it because the process of calling the taskWithURL never stops, it keeps trying to connect with the server.

Does anyone know how to handle it?

**///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

With this hard code I solved my problem
**

```
if data != nil {
   var urlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
   if urlContent?.length > 0 {
      ...
   }else {
      ...
   }
}else{
   ...
}
```

This is not a good code but solves my problem for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to add a completion block to it.
Just create a function to start you download:**

```
func getDataFromUrl(url:NSURL, completion: ((data: NSData?) -> Void)) {
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
        completion(data: NSData(data: data))
    }.resume()
}
```

**Then you have to use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())**

```
getDataFromUrl(NSURL(string: "http://.....")!) { data in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        println("Finished downloading")
        // you can use the data! here 
        if data != nil {
            // there is data. do this 
        } else {
            // there is no data. do that 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Leonardo, it did not solved my problem.

I still do not know if the data from the url is being returned with something different than nothing

Comment: But I wanted to change the view if the data was not returned.. Brs no Stack hahah

Comment: @GabrielAraujo If you want to know when you get nothing back, just use the response or error variables to check. If your connection times out, for example, you'll get an error to that effect.

Comment: @jshier the problem is that I was not receiving those informations when the page was not answering, not even answering with a 404 error

Comment: If it doesn't answer you should get an error after the connection times out after 60 seconds.

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question and post your answer there. You can answer your own question like everybody else.